# How are static routes set

Tags: routing

Looking at [`man ip-route`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-route.8.html), I see this section under `protocol`:

```
static - the route was installed by the
administrator to override dynamic routing.
Routing daemon will respect them and,
probably, even advertise them to its peers.
```

How does an administrator set these?  Is there a configuration file somewhere on the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but where that route is in the config varies by distribution - and indeed by how the host has been configured. It may reside with with the interface config or in /etc/routes or be set via DHCP, or VPN, or other software running on the host.

If there is a problem you are trying to solve, please provide specifics.

Comment: That's enough for my question.  Thanks!